# Visual Studio - snippet for variable creation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way of telling Visual Studio to create the variable it will store the result of a function call into automatically?

So for example... You type:

```
this.unitOfWork.MySQLRepo.GetUsers();
```

Then you press some magic button that makes it say this instead:

```
List<User> [snippet style typeahead] = this.unitOfWork.MySQLRepo.GetUsers();
```

Comment: ReSharper can do this

Comment: is prepending `var [myVarname] = ` (so in the end just `var` and `=` on top) really such a pain?

Comment: @CarstenKönig -- your comment is unhelpful.

Comment: Is doing the dishes really such a pain? No... But I'll get a dish washer anyway.

Comment: Even with ReSharper you have to write `var` and the variable name in this case, ReSharper only helps when the name is predictable like `foreach` loops or `switch`. Maybe I miss understood what you want, but do you want something to make up names for the variable?

Comment: @ZivS Not true.  There is an entry for "introduce variable" that then does exactly what the OP wants, highlighting first the `var`, so you can turn it into whatever type you want.  You then hit tab, and it highlights the pregenerated variable name so you can change it to something more suitable if required.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I see it now, never needed it...sorry for misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty offtopic for Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure the existing answer is what you were asking for.  Here is what ReSharper offers by way of comparison:

I start off with this line of code, with the caret at the end:

[image]

I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, ReSharper's standard combination, and get this menu:

[image]

I choose "Introduce variable", and this happens, allowing me to choose either `var` or `List<User>` for the type, or in the standard snippet way, just overtype it with something entirely different if I choose:

[image]

I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the same thing happens on the generated variable name:

[image]

again you can choose from the pre-generated names (which, if you follow standard .NET naming conventions, are usually pretty good - taking into account things like plural/singular returns, lists etc), or overtype it with your own variable name.  Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and you're back to the caret at the end of the line.

Comment: You may perceive ReSharper as being expensive.  I perceive it as being a fantastic tool in my box that has paid for itself many times over.

Comment: I assume you've just got the trial... this really is just scratching the surface of what it does!

Comment: Yes, when I have more time, I will look further into it. But it's exactly what I wanted man!

Answer (score 1):

I know one thing about rehsarper - it is expensive.

I personally have used this [Free Snippet Designer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392) and liked it too.

## Snippet Designer

[image]

- Access it by opening any .snippet file or going to File -> New -> File -> Code Snippet File
  It uses the native Visual Studio code editor so that you can write the snippets in the same enviorment you write your code.
- It lets you easily mark replacements by a convenient righ click menu.
- It displays properties of the snippet inside the Visual Studio properties window.
- Supports C#, Visual Basic, JavaScript, HTML, XML and SQL.